# OpenVPN - connect to flapping server

Tags: openvpn

I have to connect to OpenVPN server at work, which accessable via two different ISP (so, the server can be reached via 2 different IPs).

I used to put to client config these classic links:

```
remote IP1
remote IP2
```

but the problem is, ISP can be not stable, so ping **within** the VPN link become slow or completely die. So, this should be the sing for the openvpn client to reconnect to second IP.

The question is, which timeouts can be tuned to check if VPN link become "out of service" inside (the traffic can not be passed the link)? Looks like `keepalive` refers to peer's external IP and reacability, while I need "inner reacability" via VPN link.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, If the ISP is in trouble the ping latency on the external IP should be noted with higher ping, if not, please validate if the VPN server is ok and no lag happen because of external's reason. (cpu on the openvpn server if it's really the same for both ip, inner routing the same for both, etc..)

Comment: @yagmoth555, thank you for the reply, but the question is different: how can  detect if (and when) VPN link from OpenVPN cleint to OpenVPN server become dead or almost dead?

Comment: I know, it's why it's a comment :) but my point is simple, I'am not a openvpn guru, but if the vpn is slow *inside* the tunnel only, and the keepalive is nice, then you have a config error, as if a fail happen, the keepalive will fail and a simple ping on the wan side would be long. There is a lot of post about openvpn and the encryption used, the mtu used, etc.. so a lot of settings can affect you *IF* the external ping is nice and the ping from the internal is ugly.